# Pods frameworks.sh file error

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I am seeing the following error:

```
Code Signing /Users/mikesimonetta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sorealty- 
bymtwudklcqeahacubxoedmawvut/Build/Products/Debug-appletvsimulator/DEV_So's Realty.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework with Identity -
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/mikesimonetta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sorealty-bymtwudklcqeahacubxoedmawvut/Build/Products/Debug-appletvsimulator/DEV_So's Realty.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
/Users/mikesimonetta/Desktop/Projects/Clearbridge/sir-tvos/sothebysrealty/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-So_DEV/Pods-So_DEV-frameworks.sh: eval: line 113: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
```

I have looked all over for a solution to this. I have cleaned the project. I've deleted derived data. I've removed workspace/pods/lock file and built out pods from scratch. Still receiving this issue.

Any help on this blocker would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

My Podfile:

```
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :tvos, '9.0'

target 'So_DEV' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for sorealty
  pod 'GooglePlacesAPI', '~> 1.1'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
  pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 4.0.0'

end

target 'So_PROD' do
# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for sorealty
pod 'GooglePlacesAPI', '~> 1.1'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 4.0.0'

end

target 'TopShelf_DEV' do
# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for sorealty
pod 'GooglePlacesAPI', '~> 1.1'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 4.0.0'

end

target 'TopShelf_PROD' do
# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for sorealty
pod 'GooglePlacesAPI', '~> 1.1'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 4.0.0'

end
```

Comment: paste the podfile here.

Comment: @Praveen-K podfile added

Comment: @Praveen-K any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue, and it was solved by adding a post_install script in the Podfile to update the EOF character for each target. Not entirely sure what the root issue is, and why other projects I've worked on haven't had this same issue.

Found the solution/workaround here - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7090

And implemented it a little differently with some modifications to the script. It now looks like this:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'Pods-Target_2' || target.name == 'Pods-Target_1'

            frameworkPath = "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target.name}/#{target.name}-frameworks.sh"

            puts "Found #{frameworkPath}"

            text = File.read(frameworkPath)
            new_contents = text.gsub(/'\$1'/, "\\\"$1\\\"")

            File.open(frameworkPath, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents}

            puts "Updated #{target.name} framework file with proper EOF characters"
        end
    end
end
```

Hope this helps!